# How to use add-member in powershell Workflow?

Tags: object, powershell, workflow

i need to add item property but i have many error (unlike to my function code)

```
killprocess padmin7 notepad.exe
Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Error : Impossible d'ajouter un membre du type « Property ». Spécifiez un autre type pour le paramètre MemberTypes.
Au caractère killprocess:7 : 7
+
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], CmdletInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorCommand
    + PSComputerName        : [localhost]
```

my workflow source

```
Workflow killprocess ($srvs ,$process)
{
     $Processes = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -ComputerName $Srvs -Filter "name='$([string]::join("' or name='", $process))'")

    foreach -parallel ($process in $processes) {

        $Processes | Add-Member -MemberType Property -Name 'Status' -value 'in Progress'
        $returnval = $process.terminate()

        if($returnval.returnvalue -eq 0) {
            $Processes | Add-Member -MemberType Property -Name 'Status' -value 'Killed'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is using $process.terminate().  Method invocation of objects is not allowed in workflows.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/01/02/powershell-workflows-restrictions.aspx